# Return a reference to an Excel Worksheet from a PowerShell Function

Tags: excel, function, powershell, reference

For the sake of code readability, I'd like to move my Excel stuff to a function and leave the worksheet object available to write cell values as my program processes stuff. How do I call a function that creates an Excel spreadsheet and return a worksheet reference so I can continue to access the open/active Excel app object I've created?

```
Function Create-Excel-Spreadsheet() {
    # open excel
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $excel.visible = $True

    # add a worksheet
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
    $xl_wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $xl_wksht.Name = 'Cut-off'   #give the worksheet a name

    #Create a Title for the first worksheet and adjust the font
    $title_row = 1
    $xl_wksht.Cells.Item($title_row, 1)= 'Cut-off Processing Ran ' + $startday + ' at ' + $starttime_str

    #merging a few cells on the top row to make the title look nicer
    $MergeCells = $xl_wksht.Range("A1:Q1")
    $MergeCells.Select() 
    $MergeCells.MergeCells = $true

    #formatting the title and giving it a font & color
    $xl_wksht.cells($title_row, 1).HorizontalAlignment = -4108   # center the title
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.Size = 18
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.Bold = $True
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.Name = "Cambria"
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.ThemeFont = 1
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.ThemeColor = 4
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.ColorIndex = 55
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.Color = 8210719
    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($title_row,1).Font.Color = 8210719
    $xl_wksht.Rows[$title_row].RowHeight = 39
    $xl_wksht.Rows[$title_row].VerticalAlignment = 2

    #create the column headers
    $header_row = 2
    $data_row_start = 3

    $xl_wksht.Rows[$header_row].WrapText = $True
    $xl_wksht.Rows[$header_row].Font.Bold = $True
    $xl_wksht.Rows[$header_row].columnWidth = 12.57
    $xl_wksht.Rows[$header_row].HorizontalAlignment = -4108

    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($header_row, 1).value2 = 'Current Load Date'
    $xl_wksht.Columns[1].HorizontalAlignment = -4108
    $xl_wksht.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@"

    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($header_row, 2).value2 = 'Export File Type'
    $xl_wksht.Columns[2].columnWidth = 26

    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($header_row,3).value2 = 'File Name to Downloaded'
    $xl_wksht.Columns[3].columnWidth = 37

    $xl_wksht.cells.Item($header_row,4).value2 = 'Source Path'
    $xl_wksht.Columns[4].columnWidth = 23

    return $xl_wksht
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the reference to the worksheet, you can update your code to make sure nothing else is printed / returned besides what you are looking for. As it stands, you are returning two variables..

```
$wksht = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet
```

1. `$wksht[0]` -> Boolean (True)
2. `$wksht[1]` -> Worksheet reference.

Second index of your return variable will have your spreadsheet reference where first is just a boolean.

[This is a good read](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/suppressing-return-values-in-powershell-functions/) from the founder of powershell as to why this happens.

If you take your code and execute it, you will find that there is a `True` printed before the object `$xl_wksht` itself is printed. What you have to do is to make sure nothing else prints on the screen except for the variable/reference you need.

Change this line in your code and you'll be able to get the reference out.

```
    $MergeCells.Select() | Out-Null # line 17 of your code. Add | Out-Null. Or, Simply remove this line as it doesnt do anything.
```

once you have updated your code, you can use a variable to get the value from your method

```
    $wksht = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet
    $wksht.Cells(5, 1) = "Test"       // Writes Test on Row 5, Col 1.
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the quick help. I may be asking a separate question about pulling it into a module and making the reference available. I've had some challenges (much trial and error) despite trying the typical suggestions with a manifest.