# Pass an Excel worksheet as an argument to another script

Tags: excel, powershell

Is it possible to open an Excel worksheet in one Powershell script and then pass the worksheet *instance* to another script?

What I have tried:

Script 1 (main script)

```
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$PSScriptRoot\MyExcelFile.xlsx")
$WorksheetMagic = $Workbook.worksheets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "MY TAB NAME"}

& .\$DynamicScriptNr2 -OptionalParam $WorksheetMagic
```

Script 2

```
param (
    [Worksheet] $WorksheetMagic
)
```

When this is run, the following error is reported:

```
Unable to find type [Worksheet].
```

I've also tried other types, such as `Excel.Worksheet`, `Excel.Application.Worksheet` and `Object`. None of these work - well, `Object` kind of works, until I try to use the parameter *variable*, then it fails.

Can this been done?

The only other option I see is that I would need to save and close the Excel in the first script before calling the second script and then opening it there. I would like to avoid this, as when the scripts are completed there will be MANY calls made and opening and closing it all the time would be slow.

**Solution**

Playing around with the solution provided by t1meless, I have now discovered that the variables in the first script are available in the second script, without having to pass any parameters at all ... not the behaviour I expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a reference to an Excel Worksheet from a PowerShell Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725590/return-a-reference-to-an-excel-worksheet-from-a-powershell-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not specifying the type at all. This works for me:

Script 1:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$PSScriptRoot\MyExcelFile.xlsx")
$WorksheetMagic = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item("MY TAB NAME")
& .\$DynamicScriptNr2 -WorksheetMagic $WorksheetMagic
```

Script 2:

```
param (
    $WorksheetMagic
)

$WorksheetMagic.Range("A1").Text
```